# How to crawl through link to ifnormation I need

Tags: python, scrapy

I have to get all reviews text and scores from page of a product and i managed to:

With adding manual link to page with single product review  I get all reviews and scores from page(including other pages of review)

And to speed up this process I wanted to from categories page go to product page and get all reviews and scores after this is done proceed to another product.

```py
import scrapy


class ReviewAutoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'automatic'

    start_urls = ['https://www.ceneo.pl/Gry_bez_pradu']

    def parse(self, response):
        # follow links to website with review
        for href in response.css('a.product-rewiews-link + a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_link)

        # follow pagination links
        #for href in response.css('li.arrow-next a::attr(href)'):
         #   yield response.follow(href, self.parse)

    def parse_link(self, response):
        #get all reviews+score on page 
        for review in response.css('li.review-box'):
            yield {
             'score': review.css('span.review-score-count::text').get(),
             'text': review.css('p.product-review-body::text').getall(),
            }
        # follow pagination links
        for href in response.css('li.arrow-next a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: i can't enter into link with crawler and get reviews+scores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the following solution should work. The links you were getting only had the second part of the link , '/19838632', you need to use `response.urljoin('/19838632')` to get the full link. 
Also the way the spider is currently setup you are going to be making a large number of requests to the site concurrently, therefore I would highly recommend using a proxy service.

`python

```
import scrapy
class ReviewAutoSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'automatic'

    start_urls = ['https://www.ceneo.pl/Gry_bez_pradu']

    def parse(self, response):
        # follow links to website with review
        for href in response.css('a.product-rewiews-link + a::attr(href)'):
            yield scrapy.Request(href, callback = self.parse)

        for href in response.css('.cat-prod-row-name a::attr(href)').extract():
            link = response.urljoin(href)
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback = self.parse)

        next_page_link = response.css('li[class ="page-arrow arrow-next"] a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        next_page_link = response.urljoin(next_page_link)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page_link, callback = self.parse)


    def parse_link(self, response):
        #get all reviews+score on page
        for review in response.css('li.review-box'):
            yield {
             'score': review.css('span.review-score-count::text').get(),
             'text': review.css('p.product-review-body::text').getall(),
            }
        # follow pagination links
        for href in response.css('li.arrow-next a::attr(href)'):
            yield scrapy.Request(href, callback = self.parse)
```

`